# newline does not work with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I wrote a python script that formats a text file so I can import into my SQL. I am using python 3.5 and my code works perfectly.

However, When I try to run my code in python 2.7, it does not work and it throws this error. ( I have to use 2.7) I did not know this till after.

```
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.
```

Is there a way around this, if I don't use newline, it skips rows in my data and it shows as a blank row.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import os


my_file_name = os.path.abspath('NVG.txt')
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
BulkImport_file = 'BulkImport.txt'
remove_words = ['INAC-EIM','-INAC','TO-INAC','TO_INAC','SHIP_TO-inac','SHIP_TOINAC']


with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    cr =  csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(next(cr)[:25])
    for line in (r[0:25] for r in cr):

        if not any(remove_word in element for element in line for remove_word in remove_words):
         line[11]= line[11][:5]

         writer.writerow(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()

with open(cleaned_file, 'r') as fin, open(BulkImport_file, 'w') as fout:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

How can I modify my code so it's compatible with python 2.7. Thanks so much!

Comment: There is no `newline` argument in python 2.7 `open` function

Comment: Is there an argument similar to newline for python 2.7?

Comment: [Python 3.5 Open function doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: What character delineates a line/row in your file?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `newline=''`. It puts the object in universal newline mode and returns the newline characters unchanged. So, for instance, `\r\n` remains. But the csv reader strips the newline so its not really needed. If you open the file in `"rU"` mode, you get universal newlines but they are translated to `\n`. But who cares, the csv reader is okay with that. Try opening in `"rU"` mode.

Comment: You could check for the version  and assign  https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.open to ```open``` for 2.7.  I don't know if this is a standard way of dealing with version differences.  version 2.7 io.open() has a ```newline``` parameter.

Comment: The python 2.x `csv` module perfers files be opened in binary mode (`rb' and 'wb') and handles newlines based on csv dialect. I hadn't noticed before that python 3.x wants `r` and `'w' with `newline=''` mode. Since these signatures are significantly different, an intermediate function that opens differently seems like the best approach.

Comment: Okay, now I'm rambling... but looking closer I agree with @wwii. `io.open` does several friendly things like newline mode and encoding/decoding. It should work in both versions of python.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: use `io.open` which has the same signature as python 3's `open`.

The `csv` module handles line ending for you so that it can deal with line endings different than local file system encodings. For instance, a dialect may want to write `\r\n` line endings even on linux. In python 2, the solution was to open files in binary mode.

In python 3, things are different. Files opened in binary mode return `bytes` objects that need decoding to become unicode string objects. You can open in text mode, but that does two things - decoding and newline translation. So the `newline` keyword was invented. It lets you open in text mode for decoding but leaves the newline terminator in the string.

This functionality is also available in the `io.open` function available on both python 2 and 3. You can use that function to get what you want. Notice that you also need to make some sort of a decoding decision. By default its whatever `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns. You may need to make a decision about how you are encoding your csv files in the first place and use that encoding in your files.

Comment: .. sixth paragraph in [Text versus Binary data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data) of the Porting Python 2 to 3 HOWTO