# RE Formula to get 2 strings and put into csv

Tags: python, regex

I have the following in text files and I need to get a simple csv with the DataSourceName,FileName

**Datastructure**
 `<DataSourceDefinitionSet>
    <TABFileDataSourceDefinition id="id1" readOnly="false">
      <DataSourceName>AirportLayout</DataSourceName>
      <FileName>\\GIS\GIS\Corporate Services\Information Services\AirportLayout.TAB</FileName>
    </TABFileDataSourceDefinition>
    <TABFileDataSourceDefinition id="id2" readOnly="false">
      <DataSourceName>Asset_Toilets</DataSourceName>
      <FileName>\\gis\gis\CITY WORKS\Infrastructure Management\Asset_Toilets.TAB</FileName>
    </TABFileDataSourceDefinition>
    <TABFileDataSourceDefinition id="id3" readOnly="false">
      <DataSourceName>BaseLayer_Text</DataSourceName>
      <FileName>\\GIS\GIS\Corporate Services\Information Services\BaseLayer_Text.TAB</FileName>
    </TABFileDataSourceDefinition>` 
**CODE**

```
import re
filename='CRC_Public_Features.mws'
input_file = open(filename)
count=0
for line in input_file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('<FileName>', line) :
        line=line.replace('<Filename>','')
        count+=1
        print str(count)+','+line
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 

1,      <FileName>\\GIS\GIS\Corporate Services\Information Services\AirportLayout.TAB</FileName>
2,      <FileName>\\gis\gis\CITY WORKS\Infrastructure Management\Asset_Toilets.TAB</FileName> 3,
```

**I want**

> 1,AirportLayout,\GIS\GIS\Corporate Services\Information
>   Services\AirportLayout.TAB

etc

I tried the following re but get no result.

'.([^ ]*)'

What can I do? I need the 2 lines for Datasource name and Filename together.

===== **FINAL CODE USED** based on accepted answer

```
import re
filename='CRC_Public_Features.mws'
data = open(filename).read()
count=0
#for line in infile:
#data=line
values = [re.findall(first+"(.*?)"+second, data) for first, second in [("<{}>".format(b), "</{}>".format(b)) for b in ["DataSourceName","FileName"]]]
ids = [re.search("\d+", i).group(0) for i in re.findall('id="(.*?)"', data)]
final_values = [ids[0]] + [i[0] for i in values]
DataSourceName=values[0]
FileName=values[1]
total=len(FileName)
with open("Output.csv", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write("ID,DataSourceName,FileName,MWS\n")
for item in FileName:
    print str(count+1)+","+str(DataSourceName[count])+","+str(FileName[count])
    with open("Output.csv", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(count+1)+","+str(DataSourceName[count])+","+str(FileName[count])+","+str(filename)+"\n")
    count+=1
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using an XML parser here?

Comment: Mostly as I was trying to get more into re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
filename='CRC_Public_Features.mws'
data = open(filename).read()
values = [re.findall(first+"(.*?)"+second, data) for first, second in [("<{}>".format(b), "</{}>".format(b)) for b in ["DataSourceName","FileName"]]]
ids = [re.search("\d+", i).group(0) for i in re.findall('id="(.*?)"', data)]
final_values = [ids[0]] + [i[0] for i in values]
```

Output:

```
['1', 'AirportLayout', '\\GIS\\GIS\\Corporate Services\\Information Services\\AirportLayout.TAB']
```

Comment: thank but where do I nominate the name of the file it is opening? is it that 'data' should be data=open(filename)?

Comment: @GeorgeC apologies for not adding that in the first place. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

With [**xml.etree.ElementTree**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=element) and [**csv**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csvreader#module-csv) modules:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, csv

tree = ET.parse('CRC_Public_Features.mws')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for i,ds in enumerate(root.findall('TABFileDataSourceDefinition'), 1):
        writer.writerow([i, ds.find('DataSourceName').text, ds.find('FileName').text])
```

---

Final `result.csv` contents:

```
1,AirportLayout,\\GIS\GIS\Corporate Services\Information Services\AirportLayout.TAB
2,Asset_Toilets,\\gis\gis\CITY WORKS\Infrastructure Management\Asset_Toilets.TAB
3,BaseLayer_Text,\\GIS\GIS\Corporate Services\Information Services\BaseLayer_Text.TAB
```

Comment: Good idea but I get >>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>>

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am still getting >>>TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function ----I am using python 2.7 and I see there's an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491158/newline-does-not-work-with-python-2-7

Comment: @GeorgeC, always add version number to the question