# how to remove trailing newline in jython

Tags: python, jython

I am writing a code in Jython where I am reading data from a csv file and writing it to another csv.

but I am facing one issue:
I need to remove the trailing newlines and if I use newline='' in open command.

Share image of how the data should be in csv file and how it is coming. [image]

the code for reading file is as follows:

```
SAP_PS = open(r'file.csv','w',newline='')
```

the line is giving expected output but in Python 3. I want same output for jython.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491158/newline-does-not-work-with-python-2-7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [newline does not work with python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491158/newline-does-not-work-with-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try doing `file.readline().strip('\n')`